# sonarqube OutOfMemoryError (PermGen space)

Tags: sonarqube

I use Sonarqube 4.5.1 (new install) with jdk7u55. 
Installed on Windows server 2012 (4 GB internal memory)

I get this message in the `sonar.log` on the server where sonarqube-webserver is installed.

```
Error occured while clicking in the pages of the webserver of sonarqube
I tried to raise the value wrapper.java.maxmemory= from 32 to 512 to 2048 but OutOfMemoryError keep occuring.
```

complete error message:

```
Exception in thread "http-bio-10.2.31.127-80-exec-3" Exception in thread "http-bio-10.2.31.127-80-exec-1" 2014.11.04 14:19:02 ERROR web[rails]  
Java::JavaLang::OutOfMemoryError (PermGen space):
Exception in thread "http-bio-10.2.31.127-80-exec-2" 2014.11.04 14:19:06 ERROR web[o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade]  Fail to render: localhost/sonar/drilldown/issues/10000?severity=MAJOR
PermGen space
    In app/views/layouts/_breadcrumb.html.erb
```

Comment: Plugins are loaded in their own classloaders, so they need additional perm gen space, particularly when they embed 3rd party libraries. Do you confirm that multiple plugins are installed in your server?

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in the ["Tuning the Web server" part of the install documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing#Installing-TuningtheWebServer), the correct place to specify JVM parameters for the Web server is the `<install_directory>/conf/sonar.properties` file and more specifically the `sonar.web.javaOpts` property.

Since SonarQube 4.5, the wrapper configuration file is used only to force the path to the Java command.